# How to make vim find the function in /home/lib/work.sh?

Tags: bash, vim, call

There is a function in my /home/lib/work.sh

```
test(){
echo "it is a test"
}
```

In my .bashrc

```
source  /home/lib/work.sh
```

Now i can call test function in terminal.
vim can't call the test function.

```
:!test
/bin/bash: test: command not found
shell returned 127
```

How to make vim find the function in  /home/lib/work.sh?

Comment: sidenote: `test` is a bad name for a bash function, even for testing because `test` is an existing bash builtin (or external command depending on your version of bash). See `help test` or `man test`. I recommend to use `foo()` which is fortunately not in use already ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test` is the name of a builin command (see: `help test`). I suggest to rename your function to `mytest` and add this after your function in your `/home/lib/work.sh`:

```
export -f mytest
```

---

See: `help export`

Answer (score 1):

You can define shell functions in bash startup files. 
Assuming you log in in graphical mode, the relevant file is ~/.bashrc:

```
new_test() {
echo "it is a test."
}
export -f new_test
```

(As others have already pointed out, it is a bad idea to use the "test" keyword as a name).

Start a new shell or execute

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

in your current shell to make the new function available.

If you run the printenv command, you will see that new_test is now defined in your user environment, where it can be accessed by other programs such as vim.

```
BASH_FUNC_new_test%%=() {  echo "it is a test."
}
```